# Unable to get permanent API access token for public app in shopify

Tags: php, oauth, shopify

I am not using the php wrapper which is already present.I am trying `POSTMAN` to make this call.
The url which I am giving is
https://shop-name.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token

The jSON POST values:

```
{"client_id": "<valid-id>",

"client_secret": "<valid-secret-key>",

"code": "<valid-code>"}
```

The error:

```
<p class="content--desc-large">Oops, something went wrong.</p>
...
<div class="content--block">
    <h3>What happened?</h3>
    <div class="content--desc">Oauth error invalid_request: Could not find Shopify API application with api_key</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well - also using PHP.

I created my array in PHP like so -

```
$data = array(
    'client_id'     => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $shared_secret,
    'code'          => $code
);
```

At first I included both: `json_encode($data)` and in my headers: `Content-Type: application/json`.  I then tried this with just sending `$data` - without using `json_encode()`, but leaving the `application/json` header.  This worked.

So send the data as a PHP array with header `Content-Type: application/json` do not use `json_encode()`.